# Renaming folders with different names or removing them?

Tags: batch-file

I need to find a way using a batch file, to find and rename a folder. The folder(s) in question are located in different user profiles, so I'm having trouble figuring out what wildcard or variable I can use.

On a more detailed approach, I have a folder that was accidentally deployed to a large number of machines. The folder was deployed to each users `Start Menu`, and contains nothing. So my help desk is getting calls about this new "test" folder that showed up over night, that has nothing or a blank text file inside it. While some users have been told to delete it, others just want us to do something about it. Because the `Start Menu` is located in each users profile, I need a way to search recursively in all user profiles `Start Menu` location, then find and rename or remove that folder.

Regardless of the location, all of the folders in questions start with the same 5 characters, but they end with the user name in `()`.  I tried using an `*`, but my command was in quotes, so it took that literally instead of looking for `xxxxx *`, where the `*` differs from profile to profile.

Is this possible, or have I confused even the best?

Here is a copy of what I am trying to make work. The first two lines determine if it is XP or Win7 and tells it where to start based on the outcome of the IF EXIST. Then it is trying to find any folder/directory named TEST, located in each users profile `Start Menu`.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Documents and Settings\" PUSHD "C:\Documents and Settings\"
IF EXIST "C:\Users\" PUSHD "C:\Users\"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a:d-s-h /b') do (
    IF EXIST "%%G\Start Menu\Programs\TEST" rmdir /q /s "%%G\Start Menu\Programs\TEST"
    IF EXIST "%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TEST" rmdir /q /s "%%G\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TEST"
)
POPD
```

The problem is that the full folder name is `TEST (user name)`. I have tried putting in `Test *`, but it does not work because I believe it is taking the quoted name verbose instead of using `*` as a wildcard. So the folder name is different in each profile and I need the code to key in only on the word `Test` because that would not normally be there for any other application, and not be concerned with any of the name within the parentheses. Then it needs to simply delete that folder using **RMDIR**.

No VB script, not approved here. The batch file would be pushed from a server using the same methods the folder was pushed, but we want it to check all user profiles as a lot of the machines affected do not have just one specific user. The push would have placed the folder into the `Start Menu` for any user who was logged in at the time of the push, and the push repeated itself for 30 minutes until we noticed what was happening when someone called our Help Desk about a new folder called `TEST` showing up on the Start menu. The fix would be run overnight, so no users would be logged in either.

Comment: first of all let me know for all users one way is to create folder in 'AllUsersStartMenu' then all user can access that. and other way is to create one folder for each user. so how you created. then   we will go further, and one suggestion  use the VBS rather then bat.

Comment: 1. please share what you have tried so far by editing your question! 2. provide a sample folder name; 3. where should this batch script be executed -- on each client, or on one host? 4. paths with `*`/`?` put in `""` does *not* cause the wildcards to be taken literally...

Comment: Once again: please share what you have tried and all other details by **editing your question**!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
rem Make the parent directory of the profile directory of current user
rem the current directory if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\..\" pushd "%USERPROFILE%\..\" & goto RemoveDirectories

rem Make the standard user profiles directory on English Windows XP
rem the current directory if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "C:\Documents and Settings" pushd "C:\Documents and Settings" & goto RemoveDirectories

rem Make the standard user profiles directory on Windows Vista or later
rem Windows in any language if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "C:\Users" pushd "C:\Users" & goto RemoveDirectories

goto :EOF

:RemoveDirectories
rem Find in all subdirectories a directory starting with "Test",
rem having next a space character, then an opening parenthesis,
rem any other string (user name) and last a closing parenthesis.

for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /A:D /B /S "Test (*)" 2^>nul') do rmdir /Q /S "%%~G" 2>nul

rem Restore the previous current directory.
popd
```

In comparison to your approach the important difference is option `/S` on command **DIR** to get the directories of interest from **all** subdirectories of `C:\Documents and Settings` or `C:\Users`.

This could be critical if there is a directory `Test (*)` anywhere else in the directory tree than the start menu. You could evaluate if directory to remove contains in path `Start Menu` before deleting the directory, just to make sure to delete the right directory. But that works only if all machines are running an English Windows.

```
@echo off
rem Make the parent directory of the profile directory of current user
rem the current directory if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\..\" pushd "%USERPROFILE%\..\" & goto RemoveDirectories

rem Make the standard user profiles directory on English Windows XP
rem the current directory if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "C:\Documents and Settings" pushd "C:\Documents and Settings" & goto RemoveDirectories

rem Make the standard user profiles directory on Windows Vista or later
rem Windows in any language if this directory exists on current machine.
if exist "C:\Users" pushd "C:\Users" & goto RemoveDirectories

goto :EOF

:RemoveDirectories
rem Find in all subdirectories a directory starting with "Test",
rem having next a space character, then an opening parenthesis,
rem any other string (user name) and last a closing parenthesis.
rem It is tested for safety if the directory to delete is really
rem in the programs directory of the start menu directory.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /A:D /B /S "Test (*)" 2^>nul') do (
    set "TestDirectory=%%~G"
    if not "!TestDirectory:\Start Menu\Programs\Test (=!" == "!TestDirectory!" rmdir /Q /S "%%~G" 2>nul
)
endlocal

rem Restore the previous current directory.
popd
```

Both batch files use redirections of **stderr** to device **nul** to suppress error messages caused by no directory `Test (*)` found at all (`2^>nul` for command **dir**) or the directory to remove could not be deleted (`2>nul` for command **rmdir**), for example when it is the current directory of any other process running.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `rmdir /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up my question.  And also for your code work.  I am trying it today after getting sidetracked Monday.