# Finding available users on a Windows machine in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a scenario where in I need some help.
I have an application installed by the administrator which is used by all the different users who login to the machine.
Each user shall store his data in a separate folder for example C:\Users\DummyUser\AppData\Roaming\TestData.

Is it possible for me to write a batch file which can find out all the users who login to the machine, their appropriate AppData folder and then delete them?

thanks

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/03/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-list-all-the-user-profiles-on-a-computer.aspx) details how to get the list of users and their profile folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is very similar to [Renaming folders with different names or removing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33711790/3074564)

The second batch code in the referenced answer adapted to your requirements:

```
@echo off
rem Make the parent directory of the profile directory of current user
rem the current directory if this directory exists on current machine.
if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\..\" goto :EOF

pushd "%USERPROFILE%\..\"
rem Find in all subdirectories (of C:\Users on Windows Vista and later)
rem a directory "TestData". It is tested for safety if the directory
rem to delete is really in an application data directory of a user.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /A:D /B /S "TestData" 2^>nul') do (
    set "TestDirectory=%%~G"
    if not "!TestDirectory:\AppData\Roaming\TestData=!" == "!TestDirectory!" rmdir /Q /S "%%~G" 2>nul
)
endlocal

rem Restore the previous current directory.
popd
```

The batch file needs of course administrator privileges on execution for finding and deleting all the `TestData` directories from all application data directories of all used user accounts.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `rmdir /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`